# Token expuesto en github usando .env

Tags: reactjs, github

por que github me revoca el acceso con un token expuesto en un commit? si tengo el token en una variable .env y no se sube al repo github. Estoy usando Vite JS.
gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! podrias explicar un poco mejor tu escenario? te revoca el acceso a donde? que tiene que ver vite? y que es lo que no se sube y a donde?

Answer (score 0):

esto se debe a que normalmente los archivos `.env` están hechos para guardar información sensible y que no puede estar expuesta, por lo cual github cuando detecta que subes un cambio con un `.env` piensa que es una vulnerabilidad y lo bloquea, si necesitas usar la info del `.env` desde el propio github puedes agregar estos campos
[image: imagen]